# How to find area in pixels output

Tags: python, pixel, area

I need to output the area in pixels for the binary_mole.

```
mole_1 = mpimg.imread('mole_1.png')
gray_mole = rgb2grey(mole_1)
threshold = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu(gray_mole)
binary_mole = (gray_mole < threshold)
```

My attempt to find the area in pixels is below

```
trys = np.sum(binary_mole == 255)
print('number of white pixels = ' , trys)
```

The binary_mole looks like[image]

How do I fix this or go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built in function called regionprops, that has numerous measurements.

```
import skimage.measure as meas
binary_label = meas.label(binary_mole)
measurements = meas.regionpros(binary_label)

area = measurements[0]['area']
```